# Program does not contain a static 'Main' method suitable for an entry point during docker build for ASP.NET Core 7 Web API

Tags: asp.net, .net, docker, microservices, webapi

I'm trying to build a micro services app, and started configuring my dockerfile for one of the services. But I get the error during the docker build.

I use .NET 7.

The error description:

```
7.097 CSC : error CS5001: Program does not contain a static 'Main' method suitable for an entry point [/src/TeamService/API/TaskManager.Team.API.csproj]
7.114 
7.114 Build FAILED.
7.114 
7.114 CSC : error CS5001: Program does not contain a static 'Main' method suitable for an entry point [/src/TeamService/API/TaskManager.Team.API.csproj]
7.115     0 Warning(s)
7.115     1 Error(s)
7.115 
7.115 Time Elapsed 00:00:06.79
------
Dockerfile:29
--------------------
  27 |     
  28 |     # Build the project
  29 | >>> RUN dotnet build -c Release -o /app/build
  30 |     
  31 |     # Define the publish stage
--------------------
ERROR: failed to solve: process "/bin/sh -c dotnet build -c Release -o /app/build" did not complete successfully: exit code: 1
```

My project structure:

```
/
|-- Solution file
|-- TaskService/
|   |-- TaskManager.Task.API/
|   |   |-- TaskManager.Task.API.csproj
|   |-- TaskManager.Task.Logic/
|   |   |-- TaskManager.Task.Logic.csproj
|   |-- TaskManager.Task.Repository/
|   |   |-- TaskManager.Task.Repository.csproj
|-- TeamService/
|   |-- Dockerfile
|   |-- TaskManager.Team.API/
|   |   |-- TaskManager.Team.API.csproj
|   |-- TaskManager.Team.Logic/
|   |   |-- TaskManager.Team.Logic.csproj
|   |-- TaskManager.Team.Repository/
|   |   |-- TaskManager.Team.Repository.csproj
|-- Shared/
|   |-- TaskManager.Core/
|   |   |-- TaskManager.Core.csproj
|   |-- TaskManager.Cache/
|   |   |-- TaskManager.Cache.csproj
|   |-- other class libs
```

Currently, I want to build docker image purely for TeamService

My Dockerfile:

```
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/aspnet:7.0 AS base
WORKDIR /app
EXPOSE 80

FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/sdk:7.0 AS build
WORKDIR /src

COPY ["TeamService/TaskManager.Team.API/TaskManager.Team.API.csproj", "TeamService/API/"]
COPY ["TeamService/TaskManager.Team.Logic/TaskManager.Team.Logic.csproj", "TeamService/Logic/"]
COPY ["TeamService/TaskManager.Team.Repository/TaskManager.Team.Repository.csproj", "TeamService/Repository/"]
COPY ["Shared/TaskManager.Cache/TaskManager.Cache.csproj", "Shared/Cache/"]
COPY ["Shared/TaskManager.Core/TaskManager.Core.csproj", "Shared/Core/"]
COPY ["Shared/TaskManager.Database/TaskManager.Database.csproj", "Shared/Database/"]
COPY ["Shared/TaskManager.MessageBroker/TaskManager.MessageBroker.csproj", "Shared/MessageBroker/"]

RUN dotnet restore "TeamService/API/TaskManager.Team.API.csproj"

COPY ["TeamService/", "TeamService/"]
COPY ["Shared/", "Shared/"]

WORKDIR "/src/TeamService/API/"

RUN dotnet build -c Release -o /app/build

FROM build AS publish
RUN dotnet publish -c Release -o /app/publish

FROM base AS final
WORKDIR /app

COPY --from=publish /app/publish .
ENTRYPOINT ["dotnet", "API/TaskManager.Team.API.dll"]
```

I tried

1. Removing the obj file from the `TaskManager.Team.API`
2. Rebuilding all solution
3. Added `OutputType` in my `TaskManager.Team.API.csproj` file

Comment: You WORKDIR into `/src/TeamService/API/` but that directory only contains the .csproj file. The code is copied into `/src/TeamService/TaskManager.Team.API/`. I'd suggest keeping the same directory structure and names in the image as on the host.

Comment: @HansKilian, many thanks, it helped me